# COM: excelApplication.Application.Quit() preserves the process

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, com, vba

I'm using `COM` integration to drive MS Excel from Python 2.7. I noticed a peculiar thing: when I run the following bit of code:

```
import win32com.client
excelApp = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
```

an `EXCEL.EXE` process appears on the processes list (which view using the Windows Task Manager or `subprocess.Popen('tasklist')`) as expected. I then do all the stuff I need to do no problem. However, when I close Excel:

```
excelApp.Application.Quit()
```

The process persists, even if I close the Python interpreter which started it (this kind of makes sense as Excel runs in a different process but just to be sure). The only way I've found to terminate this process is either by hand, using the Task Manager, or by calling:

```
subprocess.Popen("taskkill /F /im EXCEL.EXE",shell=True)
```

the forceful `/F` flag is necessary, otherwise the process doesn't terminate.

This isn't really a problem (I hope) but I wanted to ask whether this could cause issues when I first edit the documents "normally", then when calling Excel from python and then "normally" again? Potentially many (couple dozens) times in a row? What I'm worried about is creating conflicting versions of documents etc. Or should I just terminate the `EXCEL.EXE` process each time just to be safe?

Also I noticed that `subprocess.Popen("taskkill")` doesn't return any exceptions that I can `catch` and anylse (or am I doing something worng here?). I'm particularly interested in distinguishing between the "non-existent process" kill attempt and a failed attempt to terminate the process.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try closing any open books, telling the app to quit and delete any references to the app. I usually wrap my com objects in a class. This is what my quit method looks like.

```
      def quit(self):
        self.xlBook.Close(SaveChanges=0)
        self.xlApp.Quit()
        del self.xlApp
```

Are you calling Dispatch from the main thread? If not be sure to call

```
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
```

before Dispatch, and

```
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()
```

after Quit

Comment: Thanks, that did it:
`import pythoncom
import win32com.client
pythoncom.CoInitialize()
excelApp = win32com.client.dynamic.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
excelApp.Application.Quit()
pythoncom.CoUninitialize()`
My method to quit Excel looks somewhat like this too but I just made a simple example to illustrate the issue.

Comment: What does pythoncom.CoUninitialize() do and if I have other COM objects is it safe to call it multiple times for each quit?

Comment: @Greedo sorry I was away and haven't seen your message. Quite frankly, I don't know, sorry.