# How do I save Excel Sheet as HTML in Python?

Tags: python, html, vba, excel

I'm working with this library [XlsxWriter](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/XlsxWriter).

I've opened a workbook and written some stuff in it ([considering the official example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial01.html)) -

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('Expenses01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Some data we want to write to the worksheet.
expenses = (
    ['Rent', 1000],
    ['Gas',   100],
    ['Food',  300],
    ['Gym',    50],
)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 0
col = 0

# Iterate over the data and write it out row by row.
for item, cost in (expenses):
    worksheet.write(row, col,     item)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, cost)
    row += 1

# Write a total using a formula.
worksheet.write(row, 0, 'Total')
worksheet.write(row, 1, '=SUM(B1:B4)')

workbook.close()
```

I've gone through the docs rigorously but can't seem to find the **save as** functionality.

Is there a way (*any way*) to save the `workbook` as a **HTML** file?

If it isn't possible from python code, can I somehow write **VBA** code and call that code from python?

Comment: If you want to generate HTML then why are you writing your table data in excel? Why not directly generate HTML using your table data?

Comment: @VIKASHJAISWAL Because I already have 6 months equivalent of efforts in generating excel sheets for my project. It might involve unnecessary effort to do it from scratch again.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `win32com.client` to call a VBA macro. Assuming your file is named Bar...

**VBA:**

```
Sub SaveHTML()
ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Foo\Bar.htm", FileFormat:=xlHtml
End Sub
```

**Python:**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\Foo\Bar.xlsx')
#xl.Visible = True -- optional
xl.Application.Run("SaveHTML")
xl.Workbooks.Close
```

Modify as necessary.

EDIT: I forgot to add, using win32com to close Excel is an absolute pain. The workbooks will close, but the application itself will linger (check Task Manager). Please refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221150/cant-close-excel-completely-using-win32com-on-python) on a workaround for this.

Answer (score 4):

You can save to HTML from Python directly then attach to email:

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants

yourExcelFile = ...
newFileName = ...

xl = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(yourExcelFile)
wb.SaveAs(newFileName, constants.xlHtml)
xl.Workbooks.Close()
xl.Quit()
del xl
```

Comment: This is working partially, I have the html generated, but questions are:   #1. email can not shown. #2. how can I just save one sheet, the first one, not all sheet of workbook to a html.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use xlrd to parse your excel files before converting to html http://codingtutorials.co.uk/python-excel-xlrd-xlwt/

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

You also can try xlsx2html library
https://pypi.org/project/xlsx2html/

```
import io
from xlsx2html import xlsx2html


xlsx_file = open('path/to/example.xlsx', 'rb')
out_file = io.StringIO()
xlsx2html(xlsx_file, out_file, locale='en')
out_file.seek(0)
result_html = out_file.read()
```