# Paste Excel clip to body of an email through Python

Tags: python, email, outlook, win32com

I am using win32com.client in Python to send an email.

However I want the body of the email to be a table (HTML- formatted table), I can do it in an Excel first and then copy and paste (but how?), or directly edit the corresponding Pandas data frame.

`newMail.body = my_table` which is a Pandas data frame didn't work.

So I'm wondering if there is smarter ways for example, to combine Excel with Outlook apps within Python?

Cheers,

Comment: What do you mean by "the body of the email should be a table"? Do you want an HTML-formatted version of your table? Excel is its own proprietary format, and can't -- as far as I know -- be embedded directly in an email.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I mean a table formatted as it is in Excel. Like grid lines, number formats, alignments etc. I havent learned HTML version?

Comment: How would you do this in your normal email client?

Comment: @PatrickCollins  I'd open the Excel, choose the formatted range, copy and paste to the message part of the email...

Comment: That [implicitly converts the table to HTML, if your client supports it](http://superuser.com/questions/143228/embedding-an-excel-sheet-in-an-email). But email clients in general do no support sending arbitrary snippets of Excel tables in the body of a message.

Comment: @PatrickCollins I see. So I indeed need a HTML-formatted version of the original table. And I have to do it in Python using the win32com.client module, do you have any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are solutions regarding how to convert your Excel table to HTML here: [How do I save Excel Sheet as HTML in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631511/how-do-i-save-excel-sheet-as-html-in-python), and then you just drop the HTML into the body of your email.

Per request in the comments:

Once you have the HTML-formatted version of your table in a file called `mytable.html`, you can drop it into the email with: `newMail.body = open("mytable.html").read()`

Comment: Thank you but the link saves the Excel in html, and I wanted the table to be directly pasted to the message body of the email. Not an attachment.

Comment: Paste the HTML into the body of the email.

Comment: Say the file name is "myexcel.html", I cannot simply put newMail.body = myexcel.html since it only pastes the name of the file, other than the contents..

Comment: Glad to help. Consider upvoting and accepting this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: tbh, can you put newMail.body = open("myexcel.html").read() in your answer so that other ppl can see it more clearly?

Comment: newMail.body = open("mytable.html").read() doesn't work for me.It shows raw html code. But If I changed to newMail.HTMLbody. it says"this page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them", how can I exactly paste excel to out email body anyway?frustrated. @PatrickCollins

Answer (score 0):

I m replying on old quest , but it comes on the top in search,may be helpful.

```
import win32com.client as win32
import pandas as pd
# Read A to D column and first 5 rows

df = pd.read_excel('yourfilepath.xlsx', index_col=False, nrows = 5,  usecols = "A:D")

body = df.to_html()

outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
new_mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
new_mail.To = 'person@email.com'
new_mail.HTMLBody = (body)
new_mail.Send()
```

Comment: Is there a way to send the excel contents with the color formatting. The above solution is working fine with unformatted data.