# Outlook 2013 display HTML code instead of actual Data

Tags: windows, python-2.7, outlook, win32com

I am using `win32com.client` , `python 2.7.x` and `outlook 2013` on `windows` platform.

I need to post contents of a `HTML` file to the body of `outlook` message.
I followed the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882712/sending-html-email-using-python) ,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650518/python-send-html-formatted-email-via-outlook-2007-2010-and-win32com) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028115/paste-excel-clip-to-body-of-an-email-through-python) about how to save excel as `HTML` and paste data within `outlook`.

However , when I read the file via `win32com.client.Dispatch` , instead of seeing message, I am seeing `HTML` code.

Here is the code that converts a processed `xlsx` file to `html` format using `win32.com`.

```
#Section to convert excel workbook to html 

    myfile = os.getcwd()+ "\\" + outfile
    newfile = os.getcwd()+ "\\" + "emailData.html"
    xl = EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    #xl.Visible = True
    wb3 = xl.Workbooks.Open(myfile)
    wb3WorkSheet = wb3.Worksheets(1)
    wb3WorkSheet.Activate()
    wb3.SaveAs(newfile, constants.xlHtml)
    wb3.Close(True)
    xl.Workbooks.Close()
    xl.Quit()
    del xl
```

The output of above is `newfile` which is basically an export of xlsx file saved as html. It is then opened via `mail.body` handler which should read and display actual contents within outlook.

Here is the code for that.

```
from win32com.client.gencache import EnsureDispatch
from win32com.client import constants, Dispatch
#Create and open mail message
def Emailer(text, subject, recipient):
    outlook = Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.HtmlBody = text
    #mail.HtmlBody = open(newfile).read()
    mail.body = open(newfile).read()
    attachment1 = os.getcwd()+"//"+outfile
    mail.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
    mail.Display(True)

Emailer(pageTemplate,        
        "test subject",
        "abc@yahoo.com"
        )
```

So, when I open `newfile` (html file) using `mail.body = open(newfile).read()` it pastes `html content` within a new outlook email body.

When I open `newfile` (html file) using `mail.HtmlBody = open(newfile).read()` it's giving following error within `outlook` email body

`ERROR: This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them.`

Any ideas on this behavior?

I basically want to copy/paste `html` file (which is an export of `xlsx`) within outlook email. 
Not sure if above is correct approach or there are other alternatives.

Is there a way to paste /render HTML frames into outlook email body?

Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the HTMLBody property, but keep in mind that HTML in Outlook is rendered by Word, not IE, and inline frames are not supported.

Comment: When I set `HTMLBody`, I get `frame` error because HTML data has frames. I cant avoid that. Is there a way to paste /render frame into outlook email body?

Comment: No, as I mentioned before, HTML is handled by Word, not IE. It will display the HTML outside the frames, but the frames will not be loaded. Remember, Word does not go on the network to download the frames. Your HTML must be self contained.

Comment: I get that, but how come a simple copy and paste of the same HTML content with frames from excel to outlook works? Is there a way to achieve that through some code?