Python XLSB to XLSX using win32.Dispatch to open and save
I'm pushing an xlsb file into a SQLite database using Python. This issue I'm having is with dates being in the wrong format.
To get around it I'm simply using win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application') to open the xlsb file and save it as a xlsx file, before using pandas to load the various worksheet tabs into the sqlite database.
My code works but annoyingly leaves a blank Excel window active.
Can anyone see my error or suggest a better way?
    #File is a XLSB with dates so using EXCEL to open & save file as XLSX to maintain formatting
    xlApp = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')  # create Excel object
    xlApp.Visible = False  # hide Excel window
    xlApp.ScreenUpdating = False  # don't update Excel window (no window flashes)
    xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False  # do not display alerts like updating links

    wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename=(os.path.join(download, attachment.FileName)), ReadOnly=True)                
    wb.SaveAs(Filename=(r"c:\Users\tracker.xlsx"), FileFormat=51)  # save file as xlsx file format
    wb.Close(False)  # closes Excel workbook without saving
    xlApp.Quit()  # kill Excel process

If I comment out the wb.Close(False) unwantedly, it then closes all Excel windows I have open at the time but does not leave the annoying blank Excel window

I think this answer is the key
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71499881/6145729
