# Gracefully close the Excel application from C#

Tags: c#, winforms, office-interop, excel-interop

I am generating an Excel report from the application in C#. I would like to open the Excel file for the user to view it and may be modify it later.

However, when the user closes the Excel application, the process `EXCEL.EXE` is still running as a process and can be seen in the TaskManager.

I was looking in the forums and it seems we need to release all the the object referenced by Excel through  `ReleaseComObject(object)`.

However, I donot want to close all the objects programmatically but rather I would like to give this control to the user. So, when the user closes the Excel file, is it possible that I can close or release all the objects referenced by Excel.

Any advice/ pointers to solve the problem in this direction would help me a lot.

Thanks

Comment: There's nothing graceful about ReleaseComObject().  Just stop fretting about Excel not immediately exiting when you expect it to.  Keep doing useful work in your program, the garbage collector will do its job and takes care of releasing *all* objects.  Eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to release all handles right after you open the workbook like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8978880/850119).

The other is to use the [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) method and open the file you generated. A quick example on how to use Process.Start to open a Word document can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start).